# How do you verify a block manually?

Tags: blockchain, mining-theory, hash

From my understanding, you simply need to use a SHA256 function to hash the block's header (Block hash and merkle root) then add the nonce at the end like [this article explains](https://chrispacia.wordpress.com/2013/09/02/bitcoin-mining-explained-like-youre-five-part-2-mechanics/).

However, I can't manage to get the correct next block hash.
By using the block [#505400](https://blockchain.info/block-height/505400) :

`Hash : 00000000000000000023b89dd18f6be5a6c03a71cd864ccbdf024683114b9ce3`

`Merkle root :  a3defcaa713d267eacab786c4cc9c0df895d8ac02066df6c84c7aec437ae17ae`

`Nonce : 2816816696`

`Next block hash : 0000000000000000007625ff74171cf53e301c3e5013bf2184e2629a2da0fc8d`

What I am expecting : sha256(Hash + Merkle Root + Nonce) = Next Block Hash

However I get this : `10345cb85ffed406a47e1faf31eb8ba1160aac0fbaae3cae0cd66889f9c9f49e`

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't the way a block header is created. The block header is constructed as

1. the version
2. the hash of the previous block
3. the merkle root
4. the timestamp
5. the nBits field
6. and the nonce.

Once serialized in bytes, **the header is hashed twice** with SHA256 not just once.

A common mistake is to hash the string of hex representation of the bytes, **you must hash the bytes themselves**.

See here for more info: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_hashing_algorithm

The hash is the hash of *that block*. It does *not* give the hash of the next block following it, **there is no way to know what the next block hash will be** and there are many possible hashes it could be.

Answer (score 2):

Copied below is a short python script that walks through the verification, using input values for block 505400 from the blockchain.com block explorer:

```
import json
import hashlib

block={}

#inputs values (from https://www.blockchain.com/explorer/blocks/btc/505400)
block['blocknumber']=505400
block['version']='20000000'
block['hashPrevBlock']='00000000000000000022a664b3ff1e4f85140eddeebd0efcbe6a543d45c4135f'
block['hashMerkleRoot']='a3defcaa713d267eacab786c4cc9c0df895d8ac02066df6c84c7aec437ae17ae'
block['time']=1516561306
block['bits']=394155916
block['nonce']=2816816696

#prepare values
block['versionprepared']=bytes.fromhex(block['version'])[::-1].hex()
block['hashPrevBlockprepared']=bytes.fromhex(block['hashPrevBlock'])[::-1].hex()
block['hashMerkleRootprepared']=bytes.fromhex(block['hashMerkleRoot'])[::-1].hex()
block['timeprepared']=int(block['time']).to_bytes(4, byteorder='little').hex()
block['bitsprepared']=int(block['bits']).to_bytes(4, byteorder='little').hex()
block['nonceprepared']=int(block['nonce']).to_bytes(4, byteorder='little').hex()

#concatentate prepared values to create input to double sha256 hash function
block['hashinput']=block['versionprepared'] + block['hashPrevBlockprepared'] + block['hashMerkleRootprepared'] + block['timeprepared'] + block['bitsprepared'] + block['nonceprepared']

#double sha256 hash
block['hashoutcomputed']=(hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(bytes.fromhex(block['hashinput'])).digest()).digest())[::-1].hex()

#print results
print(json.dumps(block, indent=4))
```

The double sha256 hash computed is:

```
00000000000000000023b89dd18f6be5a6c03a71cd864ccbdf024683114b9ce3
```

As expected, this result has 18 leading zeroes (as required to meet the difficulty requirement for this block), and matches the hash for block 505400 according to the block explorer.